# Apache ignite jdbc Connection credential

Tags: javascript, ignite

Hi peoples I want to set up apache ignite server with credentials like the jdbc does .

for example.
    Connection conn  = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);

currently this connection string does not have user and password.
  It is like 
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

To do this what configurations I have to do in server so that i have to pass username and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look here:

https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/jdbc-driver#section-parameters

You should use **user** and **password** options in connection string like:

```
jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1:10800;user=ignite;password=ignite
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see [Advanced Security](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/advanced-security) section of documentation if you like to enable JDBC/thin clients username/password authentication. Please note that it requires that at least one data region is persistent.

In short:

- `persistenceEnabled=true`
- `authenticationEnabled=true`
- `CREATE USER "userName" ...` from ignite/ignite **OR**
- `ALTER USER "ignite" ...`

Comment: how can i alter this ignite user. and drop its privileges.

Comment: And create a new user with full privileges

Comment: How about `DROP USER "ignite"`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60222590/ignite-create-user-with-full-privilegesjdbc-thin-client