# Ignite create user with full privileges(Jdbc thin client)

Tags: ignite

I am stuck on creating user with full privileges.

I have created a user with name shubh. but dont know how to grant all privileges.

And want to drop the default user (user = ignite , password = ignite) privileges.

Please suggest.

Comment: I don't think, that Ignite provides role-based security out of the box. You should be able to change the default password for the "ignite" account though.

Comment: Please note that usernames can be created with UPPER case if you don't use "". Please read the following article - https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/create-user#section-description. Probably you created a new user without quotas and now it should be used as SHUBH. How to drop the user you can see in Ilia's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following:

```
DROP USER "ignite";
```

As for privileges, we don't have granular permissions in Apache Ignite yet, so if you have user it can access all tables.

Answer (score 0):

So guys from the above reply's I came to the conclusion .

Just change the password for default user .